# Why wasn't Anurag's name analogous to the respective "Devdas" character Chandramukhi?

Tags: character, book-adaptation, dev-dd

In *[ALTBalaji](https://altbalaji.com/)'s **Dev DD***, all the main characters' names share similarity with Sarat Chandra Chattopadhyay's novel [*Devdas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devdas), as it's an adaptation of it with swapped genders. Like Devdas became Devika, Paro became Parth but there was no Chandramukhi analogous; we instead got "Anurag" which doe snot sound similar to "Chandramukhi". Even the kiss between Chandni and Devika did hint at Chandni being the Chandramukhi of this story but it didn't work out.

Why wasn't Anurag's name analogous to the respective *Devdas* character Chandramukhi? Was that a nod to [*Dev.D*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev.D)'s director Anurag Kashyap, as this film was also a bold attempt to adapt *Devdas* in modern culture?